# How to best cope with No more lookup filters in Managed Package context?

Tags: managed-package, limits, isv, lookup-filter

In my managed package (delivered to many customer orgs) I have active Lookup Filters on `CustomObject__c`.

I planned to add two more but ran into the "Max. 5 Lookup Filters per Object" limitation.

How can I cope with this? I would like to deactivate an old filter and add the new one but I fear that customer upgrades will fail as my package looks like it needs 6 Filters on Install. I had similar problems with External Id fields.

Do Lookup Filters behave the same way? **Do I need to make a pre-release first, where I package the deactivated old filter, before I can package the new one?**